# Place label above each element in scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm populating my scrollview in a for loop and trying to place a `UILabel` on top of each inserted element. However, the label won't center horizontally for some reason even though I'm setting its `centerXAnchor` to be equal to each element's `centerXAnchor`. Here's a picture with the label and element's borders shown:

[image: scrollview]

As seen, the label I'm inserting isn't being centered horizontally with each element in the scrollview for some reason. Here's my for loop where I populate the scrollview:

```
for i in 0..<petsDict.count {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = petsDict[i]
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    let xPos = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos - CGFloat(20*i), y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)


    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: 200, height: 40))
    label.text = "Joy"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    imageView.addSubview(label)
    label.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Regular", size: 20)!
    label.sizeToFit()

    mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
    mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

Can anybody help me understand why my x centering isn't working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove label.sizeToFit(), this function resizes your labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0..<petsDict.count {
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = petsDict[i]
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let xPos = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos - CGFloat(20*i), y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)


let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: 20))
label.text = "Joy"
label.textAlignment = .center
imageView.addSubview(label)
label.font = UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Regular", size: 20)!

mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

}

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

Give width to label same as your imageview width and remove sizeToFit and anchor. You just need to add then textAlignment which you have already added.